# Why a new windows user profile is created when I create an Application Pool in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I was recently cleaning up my file system and observed that there were few users, which I never created directly, in the c:\users* directory. This is supposed to have all those users which was created/logged in on local machines. I observed that these usernames are same as the name of Application Pools I have created in the IIS.

To confirm I created a new Application Pool in IIS and then observed this directory. Still it was not there. Later I created a new web site, assigned this application pool and accessed that website from browser, and then I see a new user profile with the name of the new application pool.

Question is - Why does it create a user profile for every IIS Application Pool? Is it absolutely necessary to have, and can it be configured for not creating? Will there be any downside? I do not remember to have seen this in earlier IIS i.e. 6.0.

My environment - Windows 7 64 Bit, IIS 7.5

I tried to google, but most links tell me how to configure User/Identity with app pool and stuff, but nothing specific about these questions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This behaviour is because of the new security model starting with IIS 7.

#### Application Pool Identities started with IIS 7

> Application Pool Identities allow you to run Application Pools under a unique account without having to create and manage domain or local accounts. The name of the Application Pool account corresponds to the name of the Application Pool.

- [Application Pool Identities (2009)](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

The main reason is security, each application pool is isolated from each other.

#### LoadUserProfile=true Creates the User Profile Folder

From experimenting on my machine I believe this setting is responsible for the folders being created.

Having LoadUserProfile set to **true** means that IIS will load the user profile for the application pool identity. This happens when the application is actually spun up, you can test this by creating a new app pool and if the setting is **false**, no new folders should be created under C:\Users when you hit the web site for the first time.

- [IIS Documentation](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/processmodel)

According to the documentation LoadUserProfile should be **false** by default, although I have noticed that on Win 7 machines it might be set to **true** instead. You can change this default via the IIS gui:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. I tried the loaduserprofile=false and Yes it's indeed not creating the profile. This is good stuff to know.

Comment: What is the purpose of the new folder created under the Users directory? Should I place my website dlls into that folder (presently dlls are under inetpub\websitename folder)?